# Cannot access to any Windows share including localhost

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, netbios

I can't access any share from my operating system, including `\\localhost` and `\\127.0.0.1`.

I have Windows 7.

NetBIOS over IP is enabled, other computers in the network can access my shares and other computer's shares, but my operating system cannot access any share.

I have installed Windows XP within VMware, and the virtual Windows XP can access all shares including the host shares.

I can communicate in other ways like TCP, HTTP and gaming, but not access shares.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: It also doesn't work when you do `\\computername`? What do you see under "Network" in windows explorer?

Comment: i cannot access \\computername. Under "Network" i can see other computers, but when i double click on one of them, it says "Windows cannot access //xxxxxxx". in the details written: "error code 0x80070035 the network path was not found"

Comment: @user: are you running any custom firewalls or AV software on your pc? Try turning it of (temporarily) to ensure that is not the problem.

Comment: I have no AV or firewall software installed. Windows Firewall disabled.

Comment: Check if your "workstation" service is running (services.msc).

Comment: "workstation" service is running.

Comment: can u PING to other computer by IP ? if successful, PING by name.

Comment: What is your actual network IP address? Did you try going to it instead of loopback? i.e. \\192.168.1.101

Comment: Also double check your host file to make sure there are not any odd setting at: %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc

Comment: Is your network set to "Home", "Workplace" or "Public"?

Comment: I have the same problem did you solved it ?

Comment: @SimonB.Robert : I "upgraded" from windows 7 to windows 7 then it solved the problem.

Comment: The output of the `net view` command may also be useful

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/windows-7-network-error-code-0x80070035-windows/84791143-b70a-4ec2-b700-98df657fe45c

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check if you're not behind some device, like a router, which is configured to block netbios shares. Be sure to check also if you're running some limited version of Windows, like home user and stuff. Check also if your IP is within the same range as other computers, if it is fixed or attributed by dhcp server, and if the subnet mask is different from other computers on the network.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is like 5 years old now. I solved it finally by completely reinstalling Windows 7.